# D3.js utcParse() returns null

Tags: javascript, d3.js, time

I've got a date format which looks like this: `2017-02-18T09:00:00+06:00`.

This is the format I'm trying to parse it with: `d3.utcParse("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+%Z");`, but it returns `null`.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of

```
d3.utcParse("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+%Z");//+ is not needed
```

It should have been

```
d3.utcParse("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z")
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/aenTSd6nh83oT5G6DBcJ?p=preview)

Answer (score 4):

Your parsing [specifier](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format#locale_format) is not correct. The `+` in the timezone `+06:00` is actually part of the timezone and must not be included in the specifier string.

```js
var parser = d3.utcParse("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z");

console.log(parser("2017-02-18T09:00:00+06:00"));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

That looks like an ISO 8601 datetime string. Why not try `isoParse` instead of `utcParse`?

```
d3.isoParse('2017-02-18T09:00:00+06:00')
```

For me this returns:

```
2017-02-18T03:00:00.000Z
```

Which is a correctly timezone-adjusted UTC datetime.

Comment: you're my saviour